# Как заставить программу нажимать клавиши?

Tags: python

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа сама за меня нажимала кнопки с определенной последовательностью, как это сделать?

Comment: Python принципиален? Есть штуки конкретно для вашей задачи.

Comment: та впринципе нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [SendKeys](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys).

```
import SendKeys
SendKeys.SendKeys("""
    {LWIN}
    {PAUSE .25}
    r
    Notepad.exe{ENTER}
    {PAUSE 1}
    Hello{SPACE}World!
    {PAUSE 1}
    %{F4}
    n
""")
```

Comment: А как его качать? Я что-то ссылку найти не могу, а на питоне 32 идет?

Comment: http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/#binaries
>а на питоне 32 идет?
Не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Sendkeys работает только для python2.7,если же вас интересует эмуляция нажатий клавиш под python3.x,то существует [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) и [python-libxdo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libxdo/)